# Typescript: Get Exclusive Members from Union Class Type

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

How do I get the Exclusive Member from a Union Typescript?

```
selectedQueueItems: Array< TestA | TestB > = [];
```

TestA has a class member called Food, that TestB does not have. However most of the other class members are similar between each.

**Receiving Error:**

> Property 'Food' does not exist on type 'TestA | TestB'.

> Property 'Food' does not exist on type 'TestB'

Currently working with existing design in our code base.

Comment: That's what a union type means. Either `A` or `B`. A member not present in both types is excluded by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need a runtime check to ensure the method you are calling exists.

In this case, you would check to see if each object is an instance of the class that you know has a `Food` member:

```
for (const item of selectedQueueItems) {
  if (item instanceof TestA) {
    console.log(item.Food)
  }
}
```

If the objects are created with `new TestA()` or new `TestB()` then this will work fine. If you are creating those object other ways, then you would need to test that in different ways. That really depends on what those objects are and how you build them. But it may involve [discriminated unions.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions)

Comment: hi, sometimes Javascript runtime, may know know which Type Class it is? is that true? may see it as an Object only?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you ask again in a different way?

Comment: sometimes when I debug, and look at an Object type in Visual Studio code of variable, Javascript runtime lists it as a Plain Old Generic Object, instead of a class, just curious, if there is possibility, instanceof may Not work in certain situations?

Comment: If the objects are created with `new TestA()` or `new TestB()` then this will work fine. If you are creating those object other ways, then you would need to test that in different ways. That really depends on what those objects are and how you build them. But it may involve [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions).

Comment: yeah, thats what I am worried about, right now I am actually using interfaces, not classes

Comment: Oh, well you said _"TestA has a class member called Food"_ so I assumed these were classes! If you post the interfaces `TestA` and `TestB`, and the code that iterates over these items, then I could probably give you a better answer.

Comment: ok, gave points and accepted answer, will write similar question for interfaces

Comment: question posted here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62705851/typescript-how-to-get-exclusive-members-from-union-interface-type

Comment: feel free to thumbs up question also

Answer (score 0):

i think the purpose of union types is that a function can get access to the common functionality without being worried about these differences though, if your function needs to access something of a specific type you can cast the object if you know the type:

```
(selectedQueueItems as TestA).Food
```

or you can check if the object is an instance of that class if you don't know the type:

```
if (selectedQueueItems instanceof TestA) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

if you need to find exclusive members for other reasons you can do something like this:

```
const testAObjKeys = Object.keys(new TestA())
const testBObjKeys = Object.keys(new TestB())
// props that exist in TestA but not in TestB
console.log(testAObjKeys.filter(k => !testBObjKeys.includes(k)))
```

Comment: hi, sometimes Javascript runtime, may know know which instance it is? may see it as an Object only?

Comment: @marksmith527 yes, `instanceof` is part of javascript so it will know which class was that object created from, so if you don't know which class this object is created from then you should use the `instanceof` solution