# Typescript: Get Exclusive Members from Union Interface Type

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

How do I get the Exclusive Member from a Union Typescript?

```
selectedQueueItems: Array< TestA | TestB > = [];
```

TestA has an interface member called Food, that TestB interface does not have. However most of the other interface members are similar between each.

**Receiving Error:**

> Property 'Food' does not exist on type 'TestA | TestB'.

> Property 'Food' does not exist on type 'TestB'

Currently working with existing design in our code base.

Reference question:

[Typescript: Get Exclusive Members from Union Class Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62704456/typescript-get-exclusive-members-from-union-class-type/62705113#62705113)

Comment: Can you post the `TestA` and `TestB` interfaces?

Comment: hi @AlexWayne well lets say interface A has 25 members, interface B has 20 members, say 15 are similar, others are different, actually could not paste real code from company, different data types, numbers, strings, boolean, they can also have Subset Nested Interfaces

Comment: does javascript have similar issues, as you mentioned earlier for Interfaces? "If the objects are created with new TestA() or new TestB() then this will work fine. If you are creating those object other ways, then you would need to test that in different ways. That really depends on what those objects are and how you build them."

Comment: Typescript helps you guard against those cases, and will raise type errors for you to work through if you are testing the object the wrong way. So don't worry about it too much. For example the three cases I covered so far are: classes, interfaces that share a common property, interfaces that share no common properties. How to tell the difference between two things obviously depends on the differences between those two things. So it's hard to give more help without specifics from your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to have each interface have a common property that has a unique value for each type in the union. This is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions).

That might look something like:

```
interface TestA {
  type: 'A'
  Food: string
}

interface TestB {
  type: 'B'
}
```

With that setup, you can test for `item.type === 'A'` and then typescript knows that you have object of type `TestA`.

That might look like this:

```
for (const item of selectedQueueItems) {
  if (item.type === 'A') {
    // item is known to be a TestA in this scope, since only TestA has: .type === 'A'
    console.log(item.Food) // Works
  }
}
```

If there is no property like that, you can still check for the properties presence before you access it with a `'key' in object` check.

```
for (const item of selectedQueueItems) {
  if ('Food' in item) {
    // item is known to be a TestA in this scope, since only TestA has .Food
    console.log(item.Food) // Works
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks interesting that your code base answer for Interfaces, is different from classes in previous question

Comment: feel free to thumbs up question also